# Replace NULL values when importing CSV in a Spreadsheet

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-api

With this code I can import from a CSV to my sheet.

Now, I would avoid to display NULL values in the cells and replace them with an empty value.

What I could add to the code I use?

```
function testf() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://xxx.csv");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dest = ss.getActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var req = { pasteData: { data: response.getContentText(), delimiter: ",", coordinate: { sheetId: dest.getSheetId() } } };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: [req]}, ss.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `Now, I would avoid to display NULL values in the cells and replace them with an empty value.`, if you want to replace `NULL` in the cells with the empty value, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function testf() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://xxx.csv");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dest = ss.getActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var sheetId = dest.getSheetId();
  var reqs = [
    { pasteData: { data: response.getContentText(), delimiter: ",", coordinate: { sheetId } } },
    { findReplace: { find: "NULL", replacement: "", sheetId } }
  ];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: reqs }, ss.getId());
}
```

- In this modification, after the CSV was inserted, the value of `NULL` in the cells is replaced with `""` using the batchUpdate method. In this case, this request can be run by one API call.
- In your script, `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` might not be required to be used.

#### Reference:

- [FindReplaceRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest)

Comment: If I would to put the data in a destination sheet called "Dest1"? How could I edit the code?

Comment: @Gavis Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `If I would to put the data in a destination sheet called "Dest1"? How could I edit the code?`, in this case, how about modifying `var dest = ss.getActiveSheet()` to `var dest = ss.getSheetByName("Dest1")`?

Comment: Done, but I have this error - ReferenceError: Sheets is not defined -

Comment: @Gavis Thank you for replying. About the error message of `Done, but I have this error - ReferenceError: Sheets is not defined`, in this case, I think that can you confirm whether Sheets API has already been enabled again? If that was not the direct solution to your new issue, can you post it as a new question by including more information for correctly replicating your new issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Gavis In your 1st comment, you said `Perfect! Thanks` to my proposed answer. In this case, it is considered that you have enabled Sheets API. But at your previous reply, you say `Done, but I have this error - ReferenceError: Sheets is not defined`. So, I'm confusing your current situation. But I would like to support you. So in this case, in order to correctly understand your new issue, I would like to propose to post your current situation as a new question by including more information for correctly replicating your new issue. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Now, works! I have enabled the Sheets API cause It was a new sheet. Thanks again @tanaike

Comment: @Gavis Thank you for replying. I'm glad for it. Thank you, too.

Comment: how to force the script to return the data from CSV in plain text?

Comment: @Gavis About your question of `how to force the script to return the data from CSV in plain text?`, I would likle to support you. But the question of your reply is new question, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: sure, this is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71679144/importing-csv-in-plain-text-for-specific-ranges

Comment: @Gavis Thank you for your response. I asked a question in your new question. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I have added a comment.

Comment: Hello. In the script, how to put the CSV result in a specific sheet named 'test'?

Comment: @Gavis By the time difference, I deeply apologize for my late reply. About your new question, I found [https://stackoverflow.com/q/72217372](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72217372). I'm glad your issue was resolved.