# Importing CSV in plain Text for specific ranges

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

With this code I can import from a CSV to a Google Sheet.

I am trying, for the columns C, H, I, the possibility to import the data in plain text.

How could I proceed?

```
function testf() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://xxx.csv");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dest = ss.getActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var sheetId = dest.getSheetId();
  var reqs = [
    { pasteData: { data: response.getContentText(), delimiter: ",", coordinate: { sheetId } } },
    { findReplace: { find: "NULL", replacement: "", sheetId } }
  ];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: reqs }, ss.getId());
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand `for the columns C, H, I, the possibility to import the data in plain text.`, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: For the Col C, I have for example x,xxxxxxxx instead xx.xx.xx and for columns H and I, I have the numbers  without 0 at beginning, but when it is present, I need it.

Comment: Thank you for repling. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand `For the Col C, I have for example x,xxxxxxxx instead xx.xx.xx and for columns H and I, I have the numbers without 0 at beginning, but when it is present, I need it.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Just a simple example

```
function lfunko() {
  let s = "abcdefghijklmn<";
  Logger.log(s.split("").filter(c => c.match(/\w/)).join(""));//removes <
}
```

The complexity of the filter depends upon your data