# Put a CSV file in a specific Sheet by Name

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

With this script I would to put the CSV in a specific Sheet named "TEST".

I have tried with getSheetByName but without result.

How could I proceed?

```
function importCSVFromAPI() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("xxx");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dest = ss.getActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var req = { pasteData: { data: response.getContentText(), delimiter: ",", coordinate: { sheetId: dest.getSheetId() } } };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: [req]}, ss.getId());
}
```

Comment: Do you need to parse data from response.getContentText()?   And in the batchupdate request, you have to pass sheetname and the values in the requst.

Comment: JSON representation

{
  "valueInputOption": 'enum',
  "data": [
    {
      "range": 'string',
      "majorDimension": 'enum',
      "values": [
          array
      ]
    }
  ],
}

Comment: Hello. I would only to put the CSV in a specific sheet named "TEST". The current script put the CSV in the first sheet of the spreadsheet.

Comment: hello. I have solved with ss.getSheetByName('TEST');

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments from the original poster this was the solution:

```
function importCSVFromAPI() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("xxx");
  var ss.getSheetByName('TEST');
  var dest = ss.getActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var req = { pasteData: { data: response.getContentText(), delimiter: ",", coordinate: { sheetId: dest.getSheetId() } } };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: [req]}, ss.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code?

```
 const req = [
        {range: "TEST", // //put your sheetname here
         values: data}
      ];
//append result to Records Sheet
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({data: req, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"},ss.getId());
```

Comment: hello. I have solved with ss.getSheetByName('TEST');